# Translate Window BAT (batch) file into Python script

Tags: python, batch-file, dos

I have a Window .bat file with DOS commands that involve REM, MKDIR, ECHO, run some programs, and especially combining all the output into a log file with time stamps. I want to translate this into Python.

I tried os.system but this will not work - it will run the programs I need to run, but there is no way to connect all the statements, making sure all the logs are outputted to the right file. As I understand, each time the command line is called separately using os.system.

An excerpt example:

```
SET LOG=test.log

DEL /F /Q ..\output\

REM THE LOG STARTS HERE
ECHO test.bat started   >%LOG%
ECHO %DATE%     >>%LOG%
ECHO %TIME%     >>%LOG%

stata/e statascript.do  
matlab -r matlabscript -logfile matlabscript.log -nosplash -minimize -wait
lyx -e pdf2 document >>%LOG% 2>&1
COPY %LOG%+statascript.log+matlabscript.log %LOG%


ECHO test.bat completed >>%LOG%
ECHO %DATE%     >>%LOG%
ECHO %TIME%     >>%LOG%

PAUSE
```

---

My sample code:

```
import subprocess, time, sys, os

log = open('test.log', 'w')

p = subprocess.call(r'DEL /F /Q ..\output\\', shell = True)

log.write('test.py started\n')
log.write(time.asctime())
log.write('\n\n\n')
log.flush()

p = subprocess.call(r'%STATAEXE% /e do statacode.do', shell = True, stdout = log)
log.write(open('statacode.log').read())
p = subprocess.Popen('DEL statacode.log', shell = True, stdout = log)


log.write('\n\ntest.py completed\n')
log.write(time.asctime())
log.write('\n')
log.flush()
log.close()
raw_input("Press <Enter> to exit.")
```

The only issue I have left is: when I run this in Windows by double clicking on test.py the way I would do it with test.bat, I get this error warning message even though all the steps are completed in the end:

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Any idea?

Comment: Wait, so you have a batch file that invokes a perl script, and you want to translate the batch into Python that calls Perl? ... Really?

Comment: It seems that the core of the routine is in Perl. Why not just make it all in Perl?

Comment: It was just an example. It could be Perl, Stata, Matlab, or whatever else, and/or a combination of all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to invoke your executables. It allows you to specify things like the input and output handles for the process, so you can direct them to where you want.

Comment: That part is the easy part. What about the rest? The log files, the time stamps?

Comment: The timestamps are fairly easily handled with the `datetime` library. The log files I what I spoke of in my answer; you'd open them with the standard `open()` function and pass them to the subprocess calls.

Comment: It's a pretty short script, so do you mind to elaborate a little more with some sample code?

Comment: It's *really* all there in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). Being one of the more complex modules, `subprocess` has *lots* of documentation. `subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=some_open_file_that_i_can_write_to, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, ...)`

Comment: Okay, I tried and it sort of worked, but 2 funny things happen: whatever I append to the log using subprocess goes to the end of the file, so even if I write to the log 'completed', it will not be at the end. Also, double clicking the .py file in Windows Explorer to run it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The former is because you need to re-open the file (in append mode again) or use the file functions to seek to the end after an external program writes to it. The latter is because Windows doesn't recognize Python scripts by default.